# Socket.io keeps reconnecting, even i don't use socket.io now

Tags: node.js, socket.io, server

I've run the chatting server and delete it.

So, I don't have any file which uses socket.io

```
'use strict'
const
    express = require('express')
    ,mongoose = require('mongoose')
    ,logger = require('morgan')

const
    app = express()


// === db setting ===



// === initial setting ===
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');
app.use(express.static('public'));


// === 3rd party middlewares ===
app.use(logger('dev'));


// === router ===
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('hello world');
});


// === error handler ===


// === server running ===
app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('=== server is running ===');
});
```

However when i run the new server, it keeps showing me this message below.

How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: You are still using socket.io on the client side (but it is failing because you don't have it running on the server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows that you have some socket.io client code in front-end code somewhere (e.g. some web page attempting to use your server) that is trying to connect to to your server using socket.io but failing.

To stop this from happening, you need to remove the socket.io code from your web page.

Probably there is a line of code in your web page somewhere that looks like this:

```
var socket = io();
```

Remove that from the web page (and other references to socket.io).

Comment: @Kwang - Do you understand the difference between code running on your server and code running in a web page?  The problem is caused by code running in your web page.  The code you've posted here is your server code which has nothing to do with this particular issue.  You must have web pages that are part of your app, right?  Show us the code for those.

Comment: No I don't have any front end code. as you can see, i use res.send.

Comment: @Kwang - Uhhh, this issue is caused by front-end code that is attempting to connect to your server via socket.io.  So, you will have to either fix this in front-end code somewhere, block that front-end code from using your service or change your server to support socket.io or just live with the issue.  Those are your options.

Comment: This is so weird... like a ghost.... I did restart the server and my laptop(broser) also. but it keeps sending me that request...

Comment: @Kwang - Does this happen when your server is running, but there are no browser windows open anywhere on your computer (e.g. all no browsers are even running)?  I would guess that there is some browser window somewhere (perhaps running older code from your chat app) that is still open somewhere and is trying to talk to your server.

Comment: Ooops! you're right!!! I have one more desktop and the browser was on. After I turn that off, problem solved!! Thank you so much

Comment: @Kwang - Yeah, socket.io is persistent.  It really wants to connect, even if it is repeatedly denied.  Glad you found the ghost.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the problem is with the server, change your port number to something else like 9001

```
// === server running ===
app.listen(9001, () => {
    console.log('=== server is running ===');
});
```

It probably won't happen but you have got to see what is making those requests to the port 8000.